# preg_ match for URL slug

Tags: php, regex, apache, yii

I need to match the url slug pattern below

apple-india
apple-price-in-india

domain.com/apple-India
domain.com/apple-price-in-india

allow only small characters and - in slug.

how to achieve this using php preg_match

Answer (score 0):

You need to read and follow section 8 from [Using Custom URL Rule Classes](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#using-custom-url-rule-classes)

The custom URL class must implement the two abstract methods declared in `CBaseUrlRule`:

```
createUrl()
parseUrl()
```